# Hadoop Pig Join with data from Hbase

Tags: hbase, apache-pig

I am trying to join the data from text file with the data from hbase, but failed.

Here is the data I used.

1. C: (XXX1,06820,7)
       (XXX2,07442,9)
2. G1: (XXX1,53)
       (XXX2,54)
3. G2: (XXX1,53)
       (XXX1,53)

G1 is load from the text file and G2 is loaded from HBase.

- G1: {sn: bytearray, country: chararray}
- G2: {sn: bytearray,country: chararray}
- J1 = Join C by sn, G1 by sn
- J2 = Join C by sn, G2 by sn.

When dump J1 I can get result, but for J2 I got nothing and here is the log.

```
Successfully read records from: "/opt/inputdata/ips1"
Successfully read records from: "hbase://geoinfo1"

Output(s):
Successfully stored records in: "file:/tmp/temp410352744/tmp-403556508" -- EMPTY FILE

Successfully read 616 records (11473 bytes) from: "/opt/inputdata/ips1"
Successfully read 1354204 records from: "hbase://geoinfo"

Output(s):
Successfully stored 0 records in: "hdfs://master:9000/user/hadoop/jjj" --- EMPTY FILE
```

Is there anything wrong with my solution? What should I do if I want to load data from hbase, and join with the data from text files?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that you have loaded data into Hbase Then Use following pig script on **grunt shell prompt**

The pig script to store with HBaseStorage :

G1 = LOAD 'hbase://geoinfo1' USING org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.hbase.HBaseStorage('column_family_name:*', '-loadKey    true -gt 10000') AS (sn:chararray, country:chararray);

Comment: I got the cause. I missed the type information. After I change AS (sn, country:chararray) to AS (sn:chararray, country:chararray); It works.Thank you.